# file is overwriten in python,when open in append mode

Tags: python

WriteFile1() Code snip:

```
try:
    iOutputFile = open(IFilePath, "a")
    if iOutputFile == 0:
        return

    csvInfoWriter = csv.writer(iOutputFile,  delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')

    lenBuff = len(g_Hash)
    for value in g_Hash.itervalues():
        iValueLen = len(value)
        for index in range(0, iValueLen):
            csvInfoWriter.writerow(value[index])


    iOutputFile.close()

 except:
    print sys.exc_type
```

I'm reading one files contents, storing those in dict g_Hash.

After reading 1000 records,I'm calling WriteFile1() to write file, and **I do clear contents from dict g_Hash [By calling ClearRec() ].** Everytime I do call WriteFile1() it overwrites my outputfile.

Please help me, I want to append the data, not wanted to overwrite..

**Edit:** After removing this from code, still the problem occurs.

```
 if iOutputFile == 0:
        return
```

**Update:**

ClearRec() Code:

```
        WriteFile1()
        g_Hash.clear()
```

----------- Does ClearRec() will cause any problem? --------

Comment: @Talvalin No, that's Java.

Comment: its python, not java. All functionality works file, just overwrite problem.

Comment: You may have to post all of your code (if it's long then add a pastebin link). I wrapped the snippet in a function (without the try/except) and called WriteFile1() twice with a different dictionary and no overwriting occurred. I used Python 2.7.3 running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the append to "a+"

For a little more reference
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

> Modes 'r+', 'w+' and 'a+' open the file for updating (note that 'w+' truncates the file). Append 'b' to the mode to open the file in binary mode, on systems that differentiate between binary and text files; on systems that don’t have this distinction, adding the 'b' has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Remove following line. It always be evaluated as False.

```
if iOutputFile == 0:
    return
```

Builtin `open` in Python return file object, not file descriptor.

```
>>> f = open('1', 'a')
>>> f
<open file '1', mode 'a' at 0x000000000281C150>
>>> type(f)
<type 'file'>
>>> f == 0
False
```

Comment: @Emma, Then, check if any `open(IFilePath, "w..")` occur in your code.

Comment: nope only in this function I'm writing file, no where else is written

Comment: @Emma, If you run you code without `try ... except ...`, any error occur? If it print error, traceback, please post it as is.

Comment: @Emma, **without** `try .. except ..`.